# VueJS styles don't appear when running distribution

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I can run my Vuejs app using nom run serve, but when I build it and deploy to nginx, none of my styles appear (particularly bootstrap). All of my app logic appears correct, and all of my js and css files are served properly. Is there some obvious oversight?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when serving it locally? Eg first install the serve pkg with `npm install -g serve` then run it with (in the app dir) `serve -s dist`

Comment: open the browser console, then access the website hosted by nginx, then check your css files are downloaded successfully or all of them are 404?

Comment: no 404, errors from Nginx. Locally, I can serve -s dist and everything looks ok. From nginx, it doesn't at all right. The only message I see is this: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "https://www.mywebsite.com/css/chunk-vendors.397535f6.css".

Comment: However, safari mentioned the following: [Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/css/chunk-vendors.397535f6.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The css didn't come across as I didn't have the types defined in my nginx config.

```
types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;
 ...
 }
```